# Search for a PDF file in directory and send with outlook Mail

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to create excel vba with the below criteria:

Search for PDF files with names mentioned in column A1, A2... Multiple... in a directory and if found send that file via outlook with the searched file attachment. If file not found ignore that file and move to the next file.

The below vba I got is showing error **"Type Mismatch"** at **pfile = pfile + 1** and loop is not executing. Let me know where i am going wrong

```
Sub CheckandSend()
Dim obMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim irow As Integer
Dim dpath As String
Dim pfile As String

`'' directory that contains files

`dpath = "xxxx"

`'' loop through all files and send mail

irow = 1

Do While Cells(irow, 1) <> Empty

'' get file name in column A
pfile = Dir(dpath & "\*" & Cells(irow, 1) & "*")
'' check file exist and pdf file
If pfile <> "" And Right(pfile, 3) = "pdf" Then
    Set obMail = Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With obMail
        .To = "xxx@domain.com"
        .Subject = "123"
        .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
        .Body = "123"
        .Attachments.Add (dpath & "\" & pfile)
        .Send
    End With
    End If
pfile = pfile + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Pfile is a file, you can't increment a file with +1, probably you wish to increment irow instead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pfile` is a string. So, if you need to concatenate strings you need to use the & symbol instead.

Most probably you needed to increase the cell number as shown below:

```
Do While Cells(irow, 1) <> Empty

 '' get file name in column A
 pfile = Dir(dpath & "\*" & Cells(irow, 1) & "*")
 '' check file exist and pdf file 
 If pfile <> "" And Right(pfile, 3) = "pdf" Then
  Set obMail = Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

  With obMail
    .To = "xxx@domain.com"
    .Subject = "123"
    .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
    .Body = "123"
    .Attachments.Add (dpath & "\" & pfile)
    .Send
  End With
 End If
 irow = irow + 1
Loop
```

Comment: That worked great.. Thank you! Also is there some way it can also give me the count of files found. There can be duplicate files with same name as well.

Comment: Also the above code only search in one folder and not inside if path has multiple subfolders. Can it be changed to search in multiple subfolders.